# eth0 and wlan0 not working aftre update to 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, upgrade

I've going around lot of forums during the las few days but for the moment no solutions.

After updating to 14:04 no network activity

`dmesg` output:

```
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

`nmcli nm` output:

```
EXECUTING  STATUS    HARDWARE-WIFI   WIFI     WWAN
executing  unplugged activated    activated  desactivated
```

`lspci -v` ouput:

```
01:080:0 Netowrk controller: Ralink copr. RT2600 802.11 MIMO
         Subsystem: Acction Technology Coporation Device ee05
         Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency, IRQ 18
         Capabilities: <acces denied>
         Kernel driver in use: rt61pci
         Kernel modules: rt61 pci
```

No idea about the possible solutions....I've tried several from other posts but....not working. The network manager doesn't allow to add new connections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to restart network manager `$ sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: Yep, I've tried, got the message Wifi Networks available but if I use the network manager no wifi conection is showed and if I try to add one manually I'm getting "No session found for uid 1000) Error statting file /var/run/ConsoleKit/database...

Comment: Really don't know why but adding to /etc/pam.d/common-session these lines: session optional pam_ck_connector.so session optional pam_loginuid.so  anyone can give a short explanation about that?

Comment: Now doesn't boot X upssssss